# Limiting requests with the async and request modules

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, request

I'm combining the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) modules to make api requests asynchronously and with rate limiting.

Here is my code

```
var requestApi = function(data){

    request(data.url, function (error, response, body) {

        console.log(body);

    });
};


async.forEachLimit(data, 5, requestApi, function(err){
      // do some error handling.
});
```

Data contains all the urls I make request to. Am limiting the number of concurrent request to 5 using [forEachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback) method. This code makes the first 5 request then stops.

In the async docs it says "The iterator is passed a callback which must be called once it has completed". But I don't understand this, what should I be doing to signal that the request has completed?

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with the same problem for hours :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you shall add callback to your iterator function:

```
var requestApi = function(data, next){
    request(data.url, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
        next(error);
    });
};
```

`next();` or `next(null);` tells Async that all processing is done. `next(error);` indicates an error (if `error` not `null`).

After processing all requests Async calls its callback function with `err == null`:

```
async.forEachLimit(data, 5, requestApi, function(err){
    // err contains the first error or null
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('All requests processed!');
});
```

Async calls its callback **immediately** after receiving the first error or after **all** requests completed succesfully.